Error when using libjpeg to decode some images
I'm using libjpeg (python) to decode some strange jpg files generated by a program. The most of the times there is no problem, but it crashes with some files like this error.jpg
It generates the same error with different Python 3.x version, pylibjpeg-libjpeg versions and SO versions. Now I'm trying python 3.11 and libjpeg 2.2
Any hints?
For example, I try:
from libjpeg import decode
I = decode('error.jpg')

Result:
RuntimeError: libjpeg error code '-1038' returned from Decode(): A misplaced marker segment was found - invalid stream, found invalid huffman code in entropy coded segment


It's not "crashing", it's generating an exception.  If you use try/except to capture the exception you can choose to ignore it or do something else.

What is your question? What do you want to happen? Are asking what the error means or how to handle it gracefully or...?

This simply isn't a standard JPEG file.  It appears to be a 16-bit grayscale image, in lossless format - neither of which is commonly supported.  I couldn't find anything that could actually view the file; I'm fairly certain that libjpeg is fundamentally incapable of reading it.

From checking the file data in a hex editor, it seems like this was created using some AccuSoft software and is not a standard JPEG. So, it makes sense that libjpeg would not be able to decode it. If you really need to access the file, check their software for something that could open it.
